# mysqli select query to JS 2d array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I have seen some answers similar to this but they wont work for me.

I want to select data from a mysql database using mysqli / PHP and then pass the results to javascript.

I have the $conn stuff just above this, my  code is at the very top of the file above the html, my script tags are in the body of the html. Is the correct place to have them? This just returns undefined, and if i try tweaking it i get unexpected < in index where i try and save it to the var ar. Or i can get unexpected ';' at the same line. Code shown below return unexpected ';'.

**PHP**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$conn->close();
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ar = <?php echo json_encode($rows)?>;
    console.log(ar[0][0]);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the source code if you are getting the data in js ?

Comment: You are aware, that you miss the `?>` before `<script>` here?

Comment: Yea i have the <?php ... ?> tags sorry, when i put them in stackoverflow it was deleting the line above, when i print it out it says undefined, sometimes i can get it to print 1 if i console.log(ar);

Comment: I just edited your code and split the _php_ and _JavaScript_ to solve the confusion of `<?php ?>` open and close tags. then in this line: `var ar = <?php echo json_encode($rows)?>;` you are not ending your _php statement _ with **;** So it should be like: `var ar = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;`

Comment: Also if you add `var_dump($rows);` at the line after `$conn->close();` what will you see in your browser?